# How to improve multiword match regex

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb

I currently have the user enter a search string that can contain many words. I then separate each word and then build the regex based on each word. I then search a list of 200,000+ entries using regex search through MongoDB. It works well but the performance is quite bad. Any suggestions to the regex that might improve the performance are appreciated!

```
//this is an example search
var search = "angel alter";
var searchSplitted = search.split(" ");
    var expression = '';
    //This is how I build my regex
    for(i=0; i<searchSplitted.length; i++){
      expression += '(?=.*' + searchSplitted[i] + ')';
    }
expression += '.*';
```

Comment: If your mongo version is `v3.2`, maybe the [`$text`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) could be one option.

Comment: `var regex = new RegExp(search.split(/\s+/).join('|'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"A.*B"` is a very time-expensive regex, as regular expression search is usually greedy. So it will find `"A"`, then `".*"` will "consume" the entirety of the remaining string, and then attempt to match `"B"`. Failing that, it will release one character at the end of the string and attempt to match `"B"` again. Multiply that by the number of `".*"` in your query and you get a very poor performance.

It would be much faster to create a more complex search query instead of complex regex. So instead of trying to put your search query into a single regex, try breaking it into a conjunction of simple search conditions, one for each word. I.e. instead of "regex match A.*B.*C..." you write "(regex match A) AND (regex match B) AND (regex match C)...". A search for a single word is much faster than your query, and if it fails, any subsequent conditions are simply skipped, saving performance.

Actually, unless you need regex functionality in search query, you can get rid of regexes entirely, replacing them with plain text search, which is always faster.